# How can i send very large array to another PHP form which makes my processing fast?

Tags: php, arrays

QS. Note that "$ABH_Rec" is very very large array. While sending data using POST in php I used:

```
$sendInfo = base64_encode(json_encode($ABH_Rec));
<input type="text" name="info" id="info" value="'.$sendInfo.'" size="30"/>
```

I Received as follows:

```
$info = (array) json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['info']));
```

and process the results. but the processing takes long time. I tried using "session" (from stackoverflow results i got answer) which makes it fast but when press back button the session expires does not make sense for the application I am working. As per as I know it is not the  best & secured way of way of sending data (as per my knowledge). So How can i send large array to another PHP form.?

Comment: How large is "very large"? Kilobytes? Megabytes? More?

Comment: pressing a backbutton does not expires a session if used correctly i think

Comment: What is in  that really big array? Maybe you shoild redesign your code. And are you start session with `session_start()` on both page?

Comment: It does reset the session, if you're resetting it it'll be gone. Chrome doesn't keep those in it's memory. If I'm right.

Comment: @Tosfera for SESSION i do talk about php session Served Side =) it doesn't matter the "browser"

Comment: Not in megabytes.less than it.It contains flight search results.

Comment: Ya that's true but a php file is executed again while browsing back.

Comment: @Tosfera sure, but a good programmer doesn't unset session vars or vars if really not needed o_0 it depends on OP code

Comment: That's right, but a good programmer knows how to send data trough a lot of redirects and won't ask for 'any way to transfer a lot of information'.

Comment: @lolka_bolka .yes i start session in both pages.but when i press back button it give error message regarding session expires. Is session is best way to send data to another form.?

Comment: @Tosfera you're right, let'see however what the op can do/needs ;)

Answer (score 2):

Save the data in a temporary table on your database, tell your second page to pick it up from there and do whatever it has to do. No need to pass a `very very large array` in an HTTP request when you control both the pages and they are on same site.

Now lets assume your data  is 1 MB, imagine the time it takes for that to be transported in a request compared to being saved in a database. Then you are encoding and decoding it without any special reason.

Comment: but using database operation is expensive task as compared to other way.M I right? also there may be many client may execute the application at the same time which may cause load on database server.

Comment: If you think using a database is more expensive than posting extremely large amount of data under an HTTP POST then i'm sorry you need to research further. That assumption is mostly misguided.

Comment: ok..! If I store it session instead of database is it good & secured way & how to handle session error (expire error) while pressing back button.

Comment: @BINODDEKA: Sessions don't magically expire or terminate unless you are using them incorrectly. Keeping the work server-side would be best. What if your user is on a dialup connection and it takes 30 seconds to post the form? The server could do the work in a fraction of the time.